# Google Bigquery - TooManyRequest 429 POST Quota exceeded error

Tags: google-bigquery, ethereum

I am using bigdata via google bigquery, often datasets have 300 million rows. I am not entirely sure which quota is exceeded, and what i can do about it. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find in the Monitoring which BigQuery quota is being hit. View instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#monitoring_quota_metrics).

If you find the quota you are hitting you can request an increase. Check the process [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota).